# Chinese Evergreen plant

Tags: houseplants

My Chinese Evergreen is getting brown spots on the leaves. I have cut a few leaves off but do not know what is causing it. It is in indirect light. I put it in the bathroom on the tub where there is a skylight over it. This has been happening in different places in the house in indirect light and it does it everywhere I put it. I thought maybe it was something in the water so I used bottle water when watering it. It doesn’t make a difference. What do you think it is. I have had many Chinese Evergreens but it never happened before.I thought maybe the soil it is in isn’t right for the plant.

Comment: Browning of leaves can be caused by many different things: sporadic watering (too much or too little), to much fertilizer, lack of sun or in some cases old age. Please post some pictures. In the meantime try changing the soil.

Comment: Picture of the leaf.

Comment: I don’t know how to send a picture in here Send me your email then I can send a picture.

Comment: Hi, Marilyn! To add a picture click edit under your post, then click the image icon. When the upload window pops up, drag and drop the pic or browse it by the location it was saved in, depending on what is easier for you to do.

Comment: Hi Marilyn! We haven't forgotten about you or your problem! Are you still having trouble with pictures? See if this [detailed instruction](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/766/5547) another site in our network helps. You can also upload your picture to an online album, give us a link, and we'll bring it in! Good luck!

Comment: Have you made any changes to the soil, as @Rob suggested, or perhaps the lighting? If so, what have you done? Has it helped at all? Let us know!

Comment: In our system we don't give out emails, so we ask you for details right here at your question. Take our quick [tour] and have a look at our [help] to see what makes us different from some other sites. [Ask] is a great starting page. We hope you're still around!